# Loading html file inside <iframe>, getting #document that does not allow to do anything

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

So on my page I have `iframe` element, which `src` attribute is, for example, `index.html`, and the problem is that **I need give this `index.html` hidden overflow without managing the `index.html` itself**, I need to do this from parent html. `Index.html` itself is simple html file with classic structure, like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>...</body>
</html>
```

But when it gets loaded in the `<iframe>`, it gets placed into `#document`, which is not even a tag, so no css modifications are possible, the code looks like

```
▼ <iframe src="index.html">
  ▼ #document
    ► <html></html>
```

And I can do nothing with this inner html. When trying to get `<iframe>` children I'm getting an empty array. If I make `overflow:hidden` on all html tags in parent css, I get no result.

What should I do in my situation? What is this #document? Would highly appreciate any possible help!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement